# Erlang supervisor:start_child parameters

Tags: erlang, nntp

I'm trying to understand this bit of supervisor code from ErlNNTP and I can't make sense of it even after reading the erlang documentation (Erlang n00b) on start-child (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_child-2)

> start_connection_handler (Socket) ->
>       supervisor:start_child (?MODULE, {Socket, {connection_handler, start_link, [Socket]}, permanent, 10000, worker, [connection_handler]}).

I do't quite get the 'Socket' parameter which I expect to be a SupRef. I'm obviously not parsing the parameter list correctly or understanding the call. Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second arg to `supervisor:start_child/2` is a child specification with the format:

```
{Id,StartFunction,RestartType,Shutdowntime,ProcessType,Modules}
```

where

- `Id` is an identifier of the child which is **unique** in the supervisor, it can be any datatype.
- `StartFunction` is a tuple `{Module,Function,Args}` which is the call to start the child process.
- `RestartType` tells the supervisor how this child is to be restart, it can have the values `permanent`, `transient` or `temporary`.
- `ShutdownTime` is how much the child process is allowed to spend in termination before it is killed.
- `ProcessType` whether the child is a `worker` or `supervisor`.
- `Modules` list of modules implementing the child

The last two are used when code upgrading.

So in your case `Socket` is being use as a identifier. Doing it this way means when you start a handler for a new socket you will get a unique identifier.

Comment: Excellent. That explains it. Thanks